# Flash and Android - common future?

Tags: android, flash, adobe

Thus far, all the Android applications I've worked on, are multimedia-oriented. In this context, support for Flash in Android is very intriguing topic for me (and many others, I believe).

Do you think that HTC Hero's Flash in the browser is strong enough indication that, at one point in the future, Android will support the Adobe platform?
The inconsistency and scarcity of the info on this topic is really strange to me and the [postponement](http://www.talkandroid.com/1308-adobe-flash-player-10-for-android/) of the awaited October release of FP10 for Android doesn't make it any better.

Still, if we assume that some future version of the SDK offers the developers support for SWF files (please, don't call it FlashView...), how would that impact the Android application environment, in your opinion?

**P.S.** And somewhat related side question: Can I make a sample application that uses `WebView` + HTC Hero and loads simple Flash content as media source? Maybe simple HTML document, containing only embedded SWFObject? It would be pretty hacky, but the concept seems cool to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do you think that HTC Hero's Flash in
>   the browser is strong enough
>   indication that, at one point in the
>   future, Android will support the Adobe
>   platform?

I look at it more of Adobe supporting the Android platform. That is mostly up to Adobe. The fact that Flash Lite is on the Hero is the first step. I was kinda expecting perhaps more announcements on this front as part of the recent push of devices -- one might think Adobe would have wanted to jump on the bandwagon at that point. It might also be that they're waiting for a slightly faster crop of devices (e.g., Snapdragon), so full Flash can run nicely, or something.

> Still, if we assume that some future
>   version of the SDK offers the
>   developers support for SWF files

That is highly unlikely, any more than the Windows SDK offers developers support for SWF files. Flash might be licensed widely and appear on many Android devices, but that does not mean Flash will be in the SDK or part of the SDK toolchain. That's not really a limiting factor, any more than Microsoft's lack of support for Flash in their SDK/tools has hindered Flash on Windows.

> how would that impact the Android
>   application environment, in your
>   opinion?

Depends on what it looks like. If it is merely Flash in Web pages, it will not impact Android development much. If, on the other hand, Flash (perhaps even Flex) apps can be treated as first-class apps on the device, that will open up Android development to a new cadre of people for whom Java is not their cup of tea.

> there should be more community wiki
>   posts

So far, I have only used SO for questions and answers, so forgive me if the style of my response here differs from the SO "community wiki" norms.

> especially, when we have/had posters
>   like Reto Meier and Mark Murphy.

:: blushes ::

Comment: Mark, what would you say about my post-scriptum? I agree about the other way round - Adobe supporting Android. I'm also curious about the way RIA will come to the platform - will it be Flash-centric, or maybe HTML5-centric...

Comment: I haven't experimented enough with the Hero to say how you can use its Flash (Lite?) capability -- sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I have a hero ( and love it ) but as the web devolops I find I care less and less about flash. Frankly I feel that HTML5 is the way forward - Canvas + SVG + JS + local DB seems to be a very flexible platform for building anything from applications (see any google app) to games (see http://www.paulbrunt.co.uk/2009/09/20/berts-breakdown/). Also openvideo (to me) replaces the need for Flash video players.

Comment: OK, but still, even with Google behind its back, HTML5 relies on not-exactly-fast JavaScript, which can be issue with mobile platforms.
Also, Flash Player's ubiquity was based on its role as simple and light bridge over different platforms - if we finally get Flash for Android, a great number of existing products will become compatible with our favorite mobile OS :)

Comment: "if we finally get Flash for Android, a great number of existing products will become compatible with our favorite mobile OS " But won't they suffer from the same speed issue? How is flash any faster than JavaScript?

Comment: Yeah i've got to say although I'm no expert I have only found flash to be slower than JS. Switching on flash on my Ubuntu machine at work tends to end in disaster whereas JS seems to have 0 issues - though that may be down to the flash software I'm using rather than inherent speed issues with flash itself. YMMV of course, I'm really just speculating. It will be interesting to see how things playout, but so far my favourite is anything non-flash ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the big guys follow the money. By that I mean, the more popular the platform/product/whatever, the higher the chances are that it will be developed for and the higher the priority.

Considering Android is and will continue exploding, combined with Adobe's already existing interest to port Flash to mobile phones, and the whole fact that mobile is the future of tech, I would say it's very safe to say we will see Flash for Android, Pre, and other devices in full strength [most likely in very buggy shapes] in the near future.

Of course, we ARE talking about Adobe here, so the real answer is 'who the hell knows'.